# Starting point for Asp.Net WebApi2 application

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I write **Asp.Net WebApi2** application, which, as database, uses **MongoDB**. At start, I want to connect with database and insert some test data, but I don't know, where, in fact, the application begins. Where is the place to insert that part of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx).

You can use the Application_Start event in Global.asax since that's the code that will be executed (every time) the application starts.

> Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET application is requested. The Application_Start method is called only one time during the life cycle of an application. You can use this method to perform startup tasks such as loading data into the cache and initializing static values.